# How to set all selected rows Data in one state but from different datagrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-toolkit

**Langage used** : javascript with react, redux toolkit and mui

**Problematic** : I am trying to set all checkbox selected from different datagrid to one state

**What I have tried and done** : I tried to set first the checkbox from indivual datagrid (working, you can see it bellow) and tried to put the onRowsSelectionHandler function in the const with all datagrid (AdminTable)

Here is my reusable component for Datagrid

```
    import React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setSkillSelected } from '../slices/skillSlice';
import { useSearchBar } from '../hooks/useSearchBar';
export const TableReusable = ({ data, columns, bool }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onRowsSelectionHandler = (ids) => {
    const selectedRowsData = ids?.map((id) =>
      data?.find((row) => row?._id === id || row?.id === id)
    );

    dispatch(setSkillSelected(selectedRowsData));
  };

  const filteredRows = useSearchBar({ row: data });

  return (
    <DataGrid
      sx={{ width: 'fit-content' }}
      rows={filteredRows}
      getRowId={(row) => row?.id || row?._id || row?.CommonId} // Spécifiez la fonction pour obtenir l'identifiant de chaque ligne
      columns={columns}
      initialState={{
        pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 10 } },
      }}
      onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => onRowsSelectionHandler(ids)}
      componentsProps={{
        pagination: {
          labelRowsPerPage: `Nb par page`,
        },
      }}
      pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 15, 20, 50, 100]}
      checkboxSelection={bool}
    />
  );
};
```

Here, the component who group mulitple datagrid component in one page/component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { TableReusable } from '../../../reusable/TableReusable';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const TcgTable = () => {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state?.tcgSkill?.skills) || [];
  const columns =
    data.length > 0
      ? Object.keys(data[0])
          .filter(
            (field) =>
              field !== 'Level' &&
              field !== 'updated_at' &&
              field !== 'created_at'
          ) // Exclude 'Level' field
          .map((field) => ({
            field: field,
            headerName: field,
            width: 130,
          }))
      : [];

  return <TableReusable data={data} columns={columns} bool={true} />;
};

const AdminTable = () => {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state?.adminSkill?.skills) || [];
  const columns =
    data.length > 0
      ? Object.keys(data[0])
          .filter(
            (field) =>
              field !== 'Level' &&
              field !== 'updated_at' &&
              field !== 'created_at'
          ) // Exclude 'Level' field
          .map((field) => ({
            field: field,
            headerName: field,
            width: 130,
          }))
      : [];

  return <TableReusable data={data} columns={columns} bool={true} />;
};

const SalesTable = () => {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state?.salesSkill?.skills) || [];
  const columns =
    data.length > 0
      ? Object.keys(data[0])
          .filter(
            (field) =>
              field !== 'Level' &&
              field !== 'updated_at' &&
              field !== 'created_at'
          ) // Exclude 'Level' field
          .map((field) => ({
            field: field,
            headerName: field,
            width: 130,
          }))
      : [];
  return <TableReusable data={data} columns={columns} bool={true} />;
};

const SoftTable = () => {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state?.softSkill?.skills) || [];
  const columns =
    data.length > 0
      ? Object.keys(data[0])
          .filter(
            (field) =>
              field !== 'Level' &&
              field !== 'updated_at' &&
              field !== 'created_at'
          ) // Exclude 'Level' field
          .map((field) => ({
            field: field,
            headerName: field,
            width: 130,
          }))
      : [];
  return <TableReusable data={data} columns={columns} bool={true} />;
};

export const ListSkills = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ margin: '2em 0' }}>
        <Typography
          sx={{
            color: '#006E8C !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            margin: '0.5em 0',
          }}
          variant="h6"
        >
          TCG Skills
        </Typography>
        <TcgTable />
      </Box>

      <Box sx={{ margin: '2em 0' }}>
        <Typography
          sx={{
            color: '#006E8C !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            margin: '0.5em 0',
          }}
          variant="h6"
        >
          ADMIN Skills
        </Typography>
        <AdminTable />
      </Box>

      <Box sx={{ margin: '2em 0' }}>
        <Typography
          sx={{
            color: '#006E8C !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            margin: '0.5em 0',
          }}
          variant="h6"
        >
          SALES skills
        </Typography>
        <SalesTable />
      </Box>

      <Box sx={{ margin: '2em 0' }}>
        <Typography
          sx={{
            color: '#006E8C !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            margin: '0.5em 0',
          }}
          variant="h6"
        >
          SOFT skills
        </Typography>
        <SoftTable />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution (I don't know if it is a best practice) but it is easier to delete my data from separate collection in my db after making this.

Instead of using a general state, I have created individual state for each datagrid

I already had created slice (redux toolkit) for each datagrid (admin, soft, tcg)... So i have just add a  setSkillSelected to each slice

```
setSkillSelected: (state, action) => {
      state.selected = action.payload;
    },
```

then, I have separate each sub component

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { TableReusable } from '../../../reusable/TableReusable';
import { setSkillSelected } from '../../../slices/softSkillSlice';

export const SoftTable = () => {
  const data = useSelector((state) => state?.softSkill?.skills) || [];
  const columns =
    data.length > 0
      ? Object.keys(data[0])
          .filter(
            (field) =>
              field !== 'Level' &&
              field !== 'updated_at' &&
              field !== 'created_at'
          ) // Exclude 'Level' field
          .map((field) => ({
            field: field,
            headerName: field,
            width: 130,
          }))
      : [];
  return (
    <TableReusable
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      bool={true}
      setSkillSelected={setSkillSelected}
    />
  );
};
```

and call them in ListSkills

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
    import { TcgTable } from '../list/TcgTable';
    import { AdminTable } from '../list/AdminTable';
    import { SalesTable } from '../list/SalesTable';
    import { SoftTable } from '../list/SoftTable';
    
    export const ListSkills = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <Box sx={{ margin: '2em 0' }}>
            <Typography
              sx={{
                color: '#006E8C !important',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                margin: '0.5em 0',
              }}
              variant="h6"
            >
              TCG Skills
            </Typography>
            <TcgTable />
          </Box>
    
          <Box sx={{ margin: '2em 0' }}>
            <Typography
              sx={{
                color: '#006E8C !important',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                margin: '0.5em 0',
              }}
              variant="h6"
            >
              ADMIN Skills
            </Typography>
            <AdminTable />
          </Box>
    
          <Box sx={{ margin: '2em 0' }}>
            <Typography
              sx={{
                color: '#006E8C !important',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                margin: '0.5em 0',
              }}
              variant="h6"
            >
              SALES skills
            </Typography>
            <SalesTable />
          </Box>
    
          <Box sx={{ margin: '2em 0' }}>
            <Typography
              sx={{
                color: '#006E8C !important',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                margin: '0.5em 0',
              }}
              variant="h6"
            >
              SOFT skills
            </Typography>
            <SoftTable />
          </Box>
        </>
      );
    };
```

So in my reusable I just need to add setSkillSelected to my params and that's it

```
import React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useSearchBar } from '../hooks/useSearchBar';
export const TableReusable = ({ data, columns, bool, setSkillSelected }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onRowsSelectionHandler = (ids) => {
    const selectedRowsData = ids?.map((id) =>
      data?.find((row) => row?._id === id || row?.id === id)
    );

    dispatch(setSkillSelected(selectedRowsData));
  };

  const filteredRows = useSearchBar({ row: data });

  return (
    <DataGrid
      sx={{ width: 'fit-content' }}
      rows={filteredRows}
      getRowId={(row) => row?.id || row?._id || row?.CommonId} // Spécifiez la fonction pour obtenir l'identifiant de chaque ligne
      columns={columns}
      initialState={{
        pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 10 } },
      }}
      onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => onRowsSelectionHandler(ids)}
      componentsProps={{
        pagination: {
          labelRowsPerPage: `Nb par page`,
        },
      }}
      pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 15, 20, 50, 100]}
      checkboxSelection={bool}
    />
  );
};
```